# Why don't we read from 2 torahs on every shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, pinchas, maftir

The maftir for many holidays, from the second sefer, has to do with the korban musaf of that day. But shabbat is a "holiday" and there is definitely a korban hayom as evidenced by its inclusion in our musaf davening. Why don't we take out 2 sifrei torah on each shabbat and have a maftir each week from "uvayom hashabbat"? [I was told that somewhere there might be a tosafot about this but I don't know where to look.]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Tosfiyos Megila 23a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9660&st=&pgnum=45&hilite=) gives 3 reasons.

1- Since the Maftir of Shabbos has only 2 Pesukim and we do not read less than 3 Pesukim. We can not start from a earlier or finish with a later Pasuk as it has nothing to do with Shabbos.

2- The Haftora has to do with what we just finished reading, and if every Shabbos we read the same Maftir then all the Haftoras would be the same.

3- We only read Korbanos if they are brought as a Kapara, and the Korban of Shabbos is not brought as a Kapara.

> הא שאין מוציאין ב' ספרי תורות בכל השבתות לקרוא בשניה וביום השבת כמו
>   שעושין ביו"ט נראה לפי שאין בפרשה אלא שני פסוקים ואין קורין בתורה פחות
>   מג' פסוקים ואין להתחיל בפרשה שלמעלה או לסיים בפרשה שלמטה משום דלא הוי
>   מענינו של יום ועוד י"ל לפי שצריך להפטיר בכל שבת מענינו של יום ואי
>   קרינן בשל שבת א"כ יהא צריך להפטיר בדסליק מיניה והיינו בשבת וא"כ יהו כל
>   ההפטרות מענין אחד ועוד י"ל לפי שלעולם אין קורין בספר תורה שני בקרבנות
>   אלא באותן שבאין לכפרה כדפירש לקמן פרק בני העיר (דף לא.) שקורין בהן
>   ביו"ט ומהני לישראל כאילו הקריבום אבל קרבנות שבת אינן באין לכפרה ומש"ה
>   אין קורין בהן׃

Comment: +1 Shulchan Aruch seems to "paskin" like the first reason in OC 283. I never understood that reason because we can just read the previous pesukim which have to do with the Tamid which is offered on Shabbat as well.

Comment: @DoubleAA - i feel the same way -- when enlarge the maftir on shabbat r"c to include the shabbat musaf (not to mention that on a weekday r"c we enlarge the laining to include the shabbot musaf) so we should be able to enlarge the shabbat maftir/musaf to include the everyday.

Comment: @Gershon Gold -- the second answer seems problematic. The statement להפטיר בכל שבת מענינו של יום doesn't seem (IMHO) to mean that the haftarah is thematically specifically from the maftir reading ("what we just finished reading"). The inyan of the day often comes from parts of laining not reflected in the final aliyah.

Comment: Perhaps Tosafos gives three reasons since as you can see there are some problems with the reasons given.

Comment: This sounds pretty much like the discussion we had when we learned this sugya in Ta'anit.

Comment: Now the question is why he didn't just give the third answer -- there must be a weakness with it as well. I tried looking at the megilla citation and don't see the explicit statement he seems to invoke אין קורין בספר תורה שני בקרבנות אלא באותן שבאין לכפרה

Comment: @Dan That's his line not the Gemara's. The Gemara just says that now that we don't have a mikdash, we can still achieve kapara from sins through uneshalma farim sefateinu. It's somewhat of a chiddush to say that it's referring to the specific maftirs.

Comment: and that it is an exclusive line of reasoning

Comment: If a community would want to do so, may they?

Comment: Supplement - I believe that the reason we take out an extra Torah on Yom Tov is to avoid *tircha detzibbur* congregation "burden" / "inconvenience"). If not for that, we would only have one on Yom Tov.